# Conditional return with no else

Tags: python

I'm try to do something like that in Python:

```
return None if a is None
```

Instead of having:

```
if a is None:
   return None
```

But I get an invalid syntax error.

I tried to use `pass`:

```
return None if a is None else pass
```

But it doesn't work as well. Is there a pythonian way to do it?

Comment: what do you want to return is `a` is not `None`?

Comment: I don't think that's possible in Python.

Comment: for this trivial example you're returning `None` either way (since `None` is the implicit return value in the absence of a `return` statement)

Comment: Note that by default a function returns `None` in Python (i.e. when not returning anything). Which means that the only thing you may want to do is returning something when the opposite condition is true.

Comment: It's not a duplicate to me, as the answer to the linked post doesn't answer this one.

Comment: @CorentinPane the accepted answer shows a work-around for a one-liner, while some of the other answers explain that using the ternary operator w/o ``else`` is simply impossible due to syntax restrictions. I'd say it's the perfect duplicate for this question.

Comment: the work-around is work-around in the case of list appending, not a work-around for `return` statement.

Comment: @MikeScotty Funny how close these two question match in the code and yet the actual point is quite buried in the comments of one of the answers, not even the accepted one.

Answer (score 3):

```
return None if ...
```

is unconditional return of a conditional value.

If you want conditional return, all what you can change is put it on single line, like that:

```
if a is None: return
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax:

```
c = a if condition else b
```

is a proxy for:

```
if condition:
    c = a
else:
    c = b
```

And MUST have both branches of the condition (as detailed in the grammar description from the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) and further discussed in the corresponding [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/)), which is missing in your code. More discussion on the `if`/`else` ternary operator in Python [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator).

---

The same holds true for `return`:

```
return a if condition else b
```

is equivalent to:

```
if condition:
    return a
else:
    return b
```

---

In your code, if you do not have instructions after that condition, you could use:

```
return None if a is None else None
```

which turns out to be a pretty useless statement, as can be replaced with:

```
return None
```

or even just omitted altogether.

---

Finally:

```
if a is None:
   return None
```

is already the Pythonic version of the code.
Acceptable alternatives include:

```
if a is None:
    return
```

```
if a is None: return None
```

```
if a in None: return
```

[PEP8 Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) suggests avoiding putting multiple statements on the same line:

> Compound statements (multiple statements on the same line) are generally discouraged.

however, is open to small-body one-liners:

> sometimes it's okay to put an if/for/while with a small body on the same line

Comment: Why got downvoted?

Comment: if you add a source to justify your "MUST have [...]" I'll upvote, because that's kinda the question asked

Comment: @CorentinPane Have a nice reading :-)

Comment: Thank you @norok2 - so the way I understand it, it can't be done. Only shrink the two lines (if ... then return None....) into one. Thanks!